# Can't access Node.js Server on OS X 10.11 from other machines on LAN

Tags: node.js, macos

I've seen this question asked before but none of the suggestions are fixing it for me.  I realize this question has been asked and the usual answers are firewall (checked), ensure you are listening on all interfaces (done, .listen(port, '0.0.0.0')), and ensure nothing else is using the port (nothing is, and I've tried other ports).

I run the following node server and I can hit it from the local machine just fine (using either localhost or the machine's IP), but no other computer on the network can access it (request just times out).

No firewall is enabled and other network services (such as file shares) on the machine work fine. Is there something in OS X other than the firewall that might be blocking inbound http?

```
var http= require ('http');
var port=1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'ContentType':'text/plain'
    })
    res.end("Hello!");
}).listen(port, '0.0.0.0');


console.log('Server started on port:'+port);
```

ifconfig output:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a8:66:7f:30:be:34 
    inet6 fe80::aa66:7fff:fe30:be34%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.148 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0a:66:7f:30:be:34 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 56:a5:ec:34:2f:fc 
    inet6 fe80::54a5:ecff:fe34:2ffc%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x6 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Comment: what if you try to run some other http server on your machine, you can try `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to listen on port `8000`.  Just to verify if the issue is with your nodejs code

Comment: Great thing to check for diagnostics - thanks, but same problem.  Ran that and can hit it from the local machine using the IP just fine (I get the default directory listing) but other machines can't hit it.  It REALLY seems like a firewall issue but the firewall in "Security & Privacy" is definitely off.

Comment: are you sure you are hitting right internal IP address? you might as well try t o ping your own machine, firewall rarely blocks `ICMP` packets. Post the output

Comment: My router's diagnostic tools can ping it fine (you'll have to take my word for it - annoyingly I can't copy and paste from my router's web interface for some reason), but neither my iPhone (using Net Analyzer) or other mac's on the network can ping it.  Macs give "Host is down" error, or just "Request timeout for icmp_seq #".

Comment: Please include ifconfig in ur post as well

Comment: Added ifconfig output to question.

Comment: Try to login to your router and check firewall configuration, probably at `192.168.1.1` for you (I assume you are using `192.168.1.148` to access your machine right )

Comment: Yes, I'm using 192.168.1.148.  IPv4 and IPv6 firewall is on on the router, but there's no separate setting for a LAN vs WAN firewall - so I'd assume that is the WAN firewall.  No DMZ enabled.  Only filter is "Anonymous internet requests".

Comment: I just tried setting up an adhoc network from the serving Mac and everything works in that case.  So the router seems to be blocking some (but not all) LAN traffic, which is super annoying.  It's a Linksys EA3500 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it although the solution is not ideal.

I added a port forward rule for port `1337` on the WAN to direct to the internal IP `192.168.1.148`.  Then, from other devices on the network I can hit the router's WAN IP on port `1337` and I get the server response.

This router (Linksys EA3500 N750) seems to block all sorts of LAN traffic and I can find no way to disable that (there's no AP Isolation setting to turn off).  So I guess I'd say if you do web development, this is not the router for you, but if you've found your way here, that's a work around that will allow you to continue working.

Thanks to everyone for helping me troubleshoot it and at least isolate where the problem was coming from!  Still would be interested in a less hacky solution if anyone has any ideas.